# Select multiple datasets in Chart.Js

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, chart.js

I'm new to [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) and I'm trying to draw graphs with multiple datasets. Some datasets are grouped together and user should be able to select those grouped datasets with a single click on the group. In this case a group is a set of graphs.

Using chart.js I've managed to draw the graphs but I'm stuck in the selecting part.
Sample graph should be like this
([Graphs grouped into two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms663.png)) here you can see all the graphs are grouped into two. So here user should be able to select either one group. Any other JS library other than chart.js is also fine.